# Get specific transactions of a BTC address in PHP

Tags: php, blockchain

How can I get the transactions (time/date, tx, amount) of a specific BTC address in PHP?
I get the balance this way but cannot find a way to get transactions.

```
<?php
function getBalance($address) {
    return file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/de/q/addressbalance/'. $address);
}
echo 'Balance: ' . getBalance('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Comment: what data is returned from this URL? Please show us. Is it JSON? If so you can decode it into an object / array and the use it like any other PHP variable to get the values within it. Or are you saying you need to know a different URL to get this data? If so then...does this website provide documentation? If not, have you asked their support team? Should we randomly know the structure of a 3rd-party API and tell you?

Comment: https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api, https://blockchain.info/q

Comment: It does not return a json, but a simple balance value. I indeed need a JSON. Looking for options without blockchain.info API

Comment: Well it seems that https://blockchain.info/q gives you the options... And what's wrong with the other API I mentioned? That will definitely give you a list of the transactions of a single address (via the `https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address` URL as far as I can see)...and it returns JSON

Comment: Thanks Adyson. My issue here is probably due to the fact that I cannot « read » the json from the rawaddr parameter since I do not understand it- such a noob. Cannot get the « in « transaction clearly. Thanks for your help it is a start

Comment: If you provide a sample here perhaps we can help you to understand it. The format is not too complicated though, and if you use json_decode in PHP it'll turn it into a regular PHP array.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the transactions AND the total BTC that came in per transaction using the advice on pages like [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51794/how-to-get-the-list-of-transactions-of-input-outputs-for-a-bitcoin-address-in-js). Luckily I stumbled upon [this](https://tangleskills.com/get-bitcoin-address-details-and-transaction-list-in-php/) which solves it beautifully:

```
$address = 'YOUR BTC ADDRESS';

    $transaction_list=array();
    $satoshi=100000000;
    $txnlist=file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/".$address);
    if($txnlist)
    {
      $txnlist=json_decode($txnlist,true);
      if($txnlist && isset($txnlist['txs']) && $txnlist['txs'])
      {
        $txns=$txnlist['txs'];
        foreach($txns as $txn)
         {
           $amount=$txn['result']/$satoshi;
           $time=$txn['time'];
           $hash=$txn['hash'];
           $transaction_list[]=array(
             'amount'=>$amount,
             'hash'=>$hash,
             'time'=>$time
           );
         }
        }
     $data['address']=$txnlist['address'];
     $data['total_txn']=$txnlist['n_tx'];
     $data['total_received']=$txnlist['total_received']/$satoshi;
     $data['total_sent']=$txnlist['total_sent']/$satoshi;
     $data['final_balance']=$txnlist['final_balance']/$satoshi;
     $data['transaction_list']=$transaction_list;
    }
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    die();
```

The result:

```
(
    [address] => XXXXXXXX
    [total_txn] => 2
    [total_received] => 0.00917981
    [total_sent] => 0
    [final_balance] => 0.00917981
    [transaction_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 0.00298651
                    [hash] => XXXXXXX
                    [time] => 1235576379
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 0.0061933
                    [hash] => XXXXXXXXXX
                    [time] => 1632561967
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: beautifully but in a centralized way

Comment: yes, the alternative is running a node, sadly.